# Read .txt file with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can you read a txt file in javascript with the file path in the code? Not by selecting the file from the open file window.

Comment: Load it with use of XHR.

Comment: Yes you can, it's called ajax, or more specifically XMLHttpRequest, good luck with that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file

Comment: No you can't. Without user interaction you cannot access any file on the local system on a typical browser.

Comment: The best way to find out the answer to these kinds of questions is to try. If you can't figure that out, search the internet. If you can't find it on the internet, ask a question on SO about the specific problems you're having.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file#14446538

Comment: @people No-one said it's local (nor on the server) so... please Alb, clarify your thoughts and show what you tried and researched about that topic. Don't ask  others to use Google instead of you ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan its a local file from my pc

Answer (score 1):

**If the textfile is on a local or private          PC**

As you may understand if you could read a textfile that is stored on a user's filesystem everyone would be able to steal private data, so in short **NO you can't**.

**If your textfile is on your server**

***ajax***

```
function ajax(a,b,c){ // Url, Callback, just a placeholder
 c=new XMLHttpRequest;
 c.open('GET',a);
 c.onload=b;
 c.send()
}
```

how to use:

```
ajax('http://YOURSERVER/yourtextfile.txt',function(){
 alert(this.response);
});
```

[more about the above function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18309057/2450730)

**If your textfile is on a different server**

When you tray to access other servers with ajax [*you need to be allowed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) to access that file. some sites allow it by returning

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

in the response heaeders.so the above ajax function would work properly.

---

Then there are other ways to get data from your or other servers that i prefer over ajax:

[websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) & [SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource).. but those need a specific interface like php or nodejs.

**Another option is if the file is on your private pc** and you just want to send some data that is stored in a specific textfile everytime you update:

Just install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) or a free PHP server and create some sort of cron job to check a specific folder everyonce a while. When the file is updated just send it to your online server. Again the online host needs at least PHP ASP or some sort of serverside scripting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use XHR (XML Http Request). Below is an example for reading a '.txt' file. You can have this in an **html** file and will need to run a simple server using **NodeJS**, **Python Simple Server** or any other server that you are comfortable with.

**1** If you have python:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

**2** Example (readtxt.html):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'filename.txt', false);  // `false` => synchronous request
request.send(null);

if (request.status === 200) {
  console.log(request.responseText);
}
</script>
```

**3** Open: 
    http://localhost:8000/readtxt.html

**4** Check the browser console for content read from the txt file.

You can read this for more detailed information,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Asynchronous_request